# How can I display a GLSL fragment shader in a WebGL canvas in angular (9)?

Tags: angular, canvas, glsl, webgl, fragment-shader

*This is my first time working on a project built with angular, so I'm still getting used to a good deal of practices specific to it and WebPack.*

I am looking to load a custom fragment shader (.frag/.glsl) in a fullscreen canvas to use as a background for a component. For past mockups or other projects not using angular, I managed to do so easily with the help of libraries like [GlslCanvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glslCanvas) that managed the setup of a fullscreen quad and the basic uniforms, but now I'm having trouble figuring out some errors thrown at me when trying to build my angular app.

After many hours of browsing around, I found out how to successfully import my shader code, using [GLSL-shader-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glsl-shader-loader) and adding a custom webpack configuration through @angular-devkit/build-angular and @angular-builder/custom-webpacks:

```js
# my-custom-webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(frag|vert|glsl)$/,
            use: [
                { 
                loader: 'glsl-shader-loader',
                options: {}  
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
}
```

I also learned I had to shush typescript from complaining about non-ts-modules on import by defining the needed declarations, i.e.:

```js
# my-declarations.d.ts

declare module '*.glsl';
declare module '*.frag';
declare module '*.vert';
```

At this point, the fragment shader's code is properly imported (or so I think?) and I can log it or print it out (with `{{ myShaderCode }}` for example):

```
# glsl-bg.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import frag from './myShader.frag';
import * as GlslCanvas from 'glslCanvas'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-glsl-bg',
  templateUrl: './glsl-bg.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./glsl-bg.component.css']
})
export class GlslBgComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('bgCanvas', {static: true})
  public bgCanvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

  myShaderCode = frag;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.myShaderCode);
  }

}
```

But, here's where I've been stuck: I tried using various light libraries (no big thing like three.js)  without success to run the shader code in the canvas.

When building with glslCanvas, it compiles successfully, but nothing shows up in the canvas and I'm getting this in the console:

```
ERROR TypeError: glslCanvas__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ is not a constructor
```

Whereas if I'm using [glsl-canvas-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glsl-canvas-js) (a ts port of the former), it doesn't manage to compile, giving me this log:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/glsl-canvas-js/dist/glsl-canvas.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './buffers' in '[...]\node_modules\glsl-canvas-js\dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/glsl-canvas-js/dist/glsl-canvas.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './common' in '[...]\node_modules\glsl-canvas-js\dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/glsl-canvas-js/dist/glsl-canvas.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './context' in '[...]\node_modules\glsl-canvas-js\dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/glsl-canvas-js/dist/glsl-canvas.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './iterable' in '[...]\node_modules\glsl-canvas-js\dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/glsl-canvas-js/dist/glsl-canvas.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './logger' in '[...]\node_modules\glsl-canvas-js\dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/glsl-canvas-js/dist/glsl-canvas.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './subscriber' in '[...]\node_modules\glsl-canvas-js\dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/glsl-canvas-js/dist/glsl-canvas.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './textures' in '[...]\node_modules\glsl-canvas-js\dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/glsl-canvas-js/dist/glsl-canvas.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './uniforms' in '[...]\node_modules\glsl-canvas-js\dist'

* [...] = full paths removed for simplification
```

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Angular dev, but here's a Typescript/Webpack setting from https://darvin.dev Webpack Boilerplate:

GLSL Loader for Webpack:

```
// https://github.com/unic/darvin-webpack-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack/settings/addon-glsl/index.js
// setting with raw-loader and glslify
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.(glsl|frag|vert)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      'raw-loader',
      {
        loader: 'glslify-loader',
        options: {
          transform: [
            ['glslify-hex', { 'option-1': true, 'option-2': 42 }]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would recommend to create a webgl instance outside of reactive frameworks and call it via pubsub, then you won't have an extra polling. Here's a sample helper with performant time handling, you will find it in Darvin 2.0 as demo sample.

```js
/**
 * @author tobias.frei@unic.com
 *
 * @module glsl uniform demo
 * 
 * https://github.com/unic/darvin-webpack-boilerplate/blob/master/.cli/.preview/.demo/.templates/.njk/templates/modules/m03-background/index.ts
 */

const Tweakpane = require('tweakpane');

// @ts-ignore
import vertexWobble from '@scripts/glsl/demo.glsl.vert';
// @ts-ignore
import fragmentWobble from '@scripts/glsl/demo.glsl.frag';

// Parameter object
let PARAMS: any;

const DEFINE_FPS = 35;
const DEFINE_RES = 800;
const DEFINE_RES2 = 800;
const deviceRatio = 1;

const resX = DEFINE_RES * deviceRatio,
      resY = DEFINE_RES2 * deviceRatio,
      verts = [-1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1];

let canvas: HTMLCanvasElement,
    gl: WebGLRenderingContext,
    fpsInterval: number,
    twodContext: CanvasRenderingContext2D,
    now: DOMHighResTimeStamp,
    then: DOMHighResTimeStamp,
    elapsed: DOMHighResTimeStamp,
    resFrame1: Promise<string>;

const imageDatas: ImageData[] = [],
      textures: any[] = [],
      textureLocationDarvin: WebGLUniformLocation[] | any[] = [];

// webgl uniforms
let pos: any,
    program: WebGLProgram,
    buffer: any,
    ut: WebGLUniformLocation | null,
    ures: WebGLUniformLocation | null,
    ucenter: WebGLUniformLocation | null,
    ushake: WebGLUniformLocation | null,
    upulse: WebGLUniformLocation | null,
    ublink: WebGLUniformLocation | null,
    ulight: WebGLUniformLocation | null;

const createShader = (type: number, source: string) => {
    const shader = gl.createShader(type);

    if (!shader || !source) {
      console.error('> cannot create shader');
      return;
    }

    gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
    gl.compileShader(shader);
    const success = gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
    if (!success) {
      gl.deleteShader(shader);
      return false;
    }
    return shader;
  },

  createProgram = (vertexShaderString: string, fragmentShaderString: string) => {
    // Setup Vertext/Fragment Shader functions
    const vertexShader = createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderString);
    const fragmentShader = createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderString);

    // Setup Program and Attach Shader functions
    const newProgram: WebGLProgram | null = gl.createProgram();

    if (newProgram && vertexShader && fragmentShader) {
      gl.attachShader(newProgram, vertexShader);
      gl.attachShader(newProgram, fragmentShader);
      gl.linkProgram(newProgram);
    } else {
      console.error('#dv> webgl program error');
    }

    return newProgram;
  },

  createGraphics = (vertexShader: string | null, fragmentShader: string | null) => {
    if (!vertexShader || !fragmentShader) {
      console.error('> shader missing');
      return;
    }

    createTextureObject(imageDatas);

    // Create the Program //
    const newProgram = createProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    if (!newProgram) {
      console.error('#dv> webgl create graphics error');
      return;
    }
    program = newProgram;

    // Create and Bind buffer //
    buffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);

    gl.bufferData(
      gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
      new Float32Array(verts),
      gl.STATIC_DRAW
    );

    pos = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'pos');

    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      pos,
      2,              // size: 2 components per iteration
      gl.FLOAT,       // type: the data is 32bit floats
      false,           // normalize: don't normalize the data
      0,              // stride: 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
      0               // start at the beginning of the buffer
    );

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(pos);

    importProgram();
  },

  updateUniforms = (time: DOMHighResTimeStamp): Promise<string> => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      gl.useProgram(program);

      importUniforms(time);

      gl.drawArrays(
        gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, // primitiveType
        0,                    // Offset
        4                     // Count
      );

      resolve('resolved');
    });
  },

  importProgram = () => {
    if (program) {
      ut = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'time');
      ures = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'resolution');
      ucenter = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'center');
      ushake = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'shake');
      upulse = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'pulse');
      ublink = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'blink');
      ulight = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'light');
    }
    imageDatas.forEach((_imgData, i) => {
      const temp = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uTexture' + i);
      if (temp) {
        textureLocationDarvin.push(temp);
      }
    });
  },

  importUniforms = (time: DOMHighResTimeStamp) => {
    gl.uniform1f(ut, time / 1000);
    gl.uniform2f(ucenter, ((((window.innerWidth) / 2)) / (resX / 100) / 100) * deviceRatio, ( (((window.innerHeight) / 2)) / (resY / 100) / 100) * deviceRatio);
    gl.uniform2f(ures, resX, resY);

    gl.uniform1i(ushake, PARAMS.shake);
    gl.uniform1i(upulse, PARAMS.pulse);
    gl.uniform1i(ublink, PARAMS.blink);
    gl.uniform1f(ulight, PARAMS.light);

   // Set each texture unit to use a particular texture.
   textureLocationDarvin.forEach((textureLocation, i) => {
      gl.uniform1i(textureLocation, i);  // texture unit 0
      gl.activeTexture(gl['TEXTURE' + i]);
      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, textures[i]);
    });
  },

  resizeCanvasToDisplaySize = (): boolean => {
    const glCanvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>gl.canvas;
    const width = glCanvas.clientWidth * deviceRatio;
    const height = glCanvas.clientHeight * deviceRatio;
    const needResize = glCanvas.width !== width ||
      glCanvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      glCanvas.width = width;
      glCanvas.height = height;
    }
    return needResize;
  },

  startRenderLoop = (fps: number) => {
    fpsInterval = 1000 / fps;
    then = Date.now();
    renderLoop(then);
  },

  renderLoop = async (time: DOMHighResTimeStamp) => {
    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
    // calc elapsed time since last loop
    now = Date.now();
    elapsed = now - then;

    if (elapsed > fpsInterval) {
      // Get ready for next frame by setting then=now, but also adjust for your
      // specified fpsInterval not being a multiple of RAF's interval (16.7ms)
      then = now - (elapsed % fpsInterval);

      // begin call and store promise without waiting
      resFrame1 = updateUniforms(time);

      // @ts-ignore
      const actualFrame = [await resFrame1];
    }
  },

  startShaderItems = ({vertex, fragment}: any) => {
    createGraphics(vertex, fragment);
  },

  initCanvas = () => {
    resizeCanvasToDisplaySize();
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    startRenderLoop(DEFINE_FPS);
  },

  resize = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        resizeCanvasToDisplaySize();

        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
        });
      });
    });
  },

  addDomListener = () => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
  },

  removeDomListener = () => {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', resize);
  },

  setImageData = (svgPathsArray: any[]) => {
    const canvas2D = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById('background-canvas2d');
    twodContext = <CanvasRenderingContext2D>canvas2D.getContext('2d');

    svgPathsArray.forEach((svgPaths) => {
      twodContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2D.width, canvas2D.height);

      svgPaths.forEach((svgPathNode) => {
        twodContext.fill(new Path2D(svgPathNode));
      });

      const imageData = twodContext.getImageData(0, 0, DEFINE_RES, DEFINE_RES2);
      imageDatas.push(imageData);
    });
  },

  createTextureObject = (imgDatas: ImageData[]) => {
    // create 2 textures
    for (let i = 0; i < imgDatas.length; i++) {
      const texture: any = gl.createTexture();
      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

      // Set the parameters so we can render any size image.
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

      // Upload the image into the texture.
      gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, imgDatas[i]);

      // add the texture to the array of textures.
      textures.push(texture);
    }
  },

  addTweakPane = () => {
    // get settings from storage
    const stor = localStorage.getItem('darvindoc-params');
    if (stor) {
      try {
        PARAMS = JSON.parse(stor);
      } catch {
        PARAMS = {
          light: -30.0,
          pulse: true,
          shake: false,
          blink: true
        };
      }
    } else {
      PARAMS = {
        light: -30.0,
        pulse: true,
        shake: false,
        blink: true
      };
    }

    // params panel
    const pane = new Tweakpane();
    pane.addInput(PARAMS, 'pulse').on('change', () => {
      localStorage.setItem('darvindoc-params', JSON.stringify(PARAMS));
    });
    pane.addInput(PARAMS, 'shake').on('change', () => {
      localStorage.setItem('darvindoc-params', JSON.stringify(PARAMS));
    });
    pane.addInput(PARAMS, 'blink').on('change', () => {
      localStorage.setItem('darvindoc-params', JSON.stringify(PARAMS));
    });
    pane.addInput(PARAMS, 'light', {
      min: -50.,
      max: -1.,
    }).on('change', () => {
      localStorage.setItem('darvindoc-params', JSON.stringify(PARAMS));
    });
  };


/**
 * Change framerate
 *
 * @param {number} fps - Set new fps e.g 55
 */
const setFps = (fps: number) => {
  fpsInterval = 1000 / fps;
};

/**
 * destroy all instances
 *
 */
const destroy = () => {
  removeDomListener();
};

/**
 * Initialize module
 *
 * @return {object} Instance of created module.
 * @param webgl boolean that defines wheather to use webgl or not
 */
const init = () => {
  const svgTetureObjects: NodeListOf<HTMLElement> | null = document.querySelectorAll('svg.texture-import');
  const svgTexturePathStrings: any[] = [];

  if (!svgTetureObjects) {
    console.error('> webgl: missing svg icons');
    return;
  }

  // import texture paths
  svgTetureObjects.forEach((svgTextureObject) => {
    const svgPaths: NodeListOf<HTMLElement> | null = svgTextureObject.querySelectorAll('.darvinIconPath');
    const svgPathsString: any[] = [];

    svgPaths.forEach((svgPathNode) => {
      let svgPath: string | undefined;
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-non-null-assertion
      svgPath = svgPathNode!.getAttribute('d') || undefined;
      svgPathsString.push(svgPath);
    });

    svgTexturePathStrings.push(svgPathsString);
  });

  // init canvas
  canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('background-canvas');
  if (!canvas) {
    console.error('#dv> no canvas found');
    return;
  }

  const glContext = canvas.getContext('webgl', {
    preserveDrawingBuffer: false
  });

  if (!glContext) {
    console.error('#dv> error on webgl context');
    return;
  }

  gl = glContext;

  setImageData(svgTexturePathStrings);

  gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
  gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

  startShaderItems({
    vertex: vertexWobble,
    fragment: fragmentWobble
  });

  initCanvas();

  addDomListener();
  addTweakPane();
};

export default {
  init,
  destroy,
  setFps
};
```

Have fun